# What does οὐ τὰς τυχούσας mean in Acts 19:11?

Tags: acts, paul, translation-philosophy

Most translations say something like:

> "And God wrought **special** miracles by the hands of Paul"
>
> δυνάμεις τε **οὐ τὰς τυχούσας** ἐποίει ὁ Θεὸς διὰ τῶν χειρῶν Παύλου,

But the NKJV says:

> "Now God worked **unusual** miracles by the hands of Paul,
>
> so that **even handkerchiefs or aprons were brought from his body** to the sick, and the diseases left them and the evil spirits went out of them." Acts 19:11-12

Is "special" or "unusual" a more appropriate translation of οὐ τὰς τυχούσας?

Comment: Can you specify what you think is the difference between "special" and "unusual" in this context? Obviously "unusual" is the more formal rendering (cf. 28:2), but I don't really see how "special" means anything much different here.

Comment: Thanks @Susan. In English, special means "a distinct or particular kind". Unusual means "strange" or "weird". I was just wondering if this clause usually denotes something that is different or "extraordinary" (like some translations say), or does it explain something that is weird and a little creepy?

Comment: [**Unusual**](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/unusual): _not usual, common, or ordinary; uncommon in amount or degree; exceptional._ [**Special**](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/special): _distinct / particular / peculiar / extraordinary, exceptional / distinguished or different from what is ordinary or usual._ [**Strange**](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/strange): _unusual, extraordinary, or curious; odd._ [**Weird**](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/weird): _involving or suggesting the supernatural; unearthly or uncanny / fantastic, bizarre._

Comment: Thank you @Bʀɪᴀɴ. Would this suggest that "strange" is the proper meaning of this phrase? Strange seems to be a middle ground between "unusual" and "extraordinary", because I definitely see a difference between these two words. That which is "not usual" cannot be "extra usual", right?

Comment: @anonymouswho - Is English not your native language? Because contrary to how it is spelled, ['extraordinary'](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/extraordinary) does not mean "extra usual" as in "more common than other common things," it means _beyond what is usual or ordinary_, as in _unusual/special/strange_. And yes, you could use 'strange' here because it is a synonym of 'unusual/special/extraordinary.' Taking a handkerchief that had touched Paul's body to a sick person and curing him is a very strange miracle indeed.

Comment: @Bʀɪᴀɴ, yes I know what extraordinary means. It's "beyond ordinary" because it's "ordinary" with something a bit "extra". Such as "She is extraordinary at basketball". The girl can play ordinary basketball, but there is something extra that makes her stand out. But if we said "She is unusual at basketball", this would mean she doesn't play basketball the way it's usually played. I may be wrong, but that's how I've always understood it.

Comment: + Compare [Acts 8:13](https://www.biblegateway.com/verse/en/Acts%208:13), and also "[Lukan *litotes*](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22lukan+litotes%22&hl=en&authuser=0)"

Comment: Thank you @Davïd. The *litotes* is interesting, but does not Luke only use these to denote an opposite? What I mean is, a miracle is "extraordinary" in its own right, so why add that these "extraordinary miracles" were "not usual"?

Comment: @anonymouswho - God performed miracles through Paul in ways that He does not normally perform miracles. Thus they were _unusual_ or _special_ or _strange_. No offense, but your basketball example is flawed because the sport has set rules with a rule book anyone can go to and look at. God does not have set rules for performing miracles, but He doesn't normally perform miracles by someone taking a handkerchief or apron one of his apostles had touched to a sick person and healing him with it.

Comment: `οὐ τὰς τυχούσας` *is* an example "litotes" -- perhaps worth reading about through some of the discussions at the link I provided? The 8:13 parallel suggests that Luke is using a rhetorically interesting of saying something more-or-less equivalent.

Comment: @Davïd I did read the examples, and from what I could gather, his expression meant the miracles were *highly* unusual or strange, whereas the miracles of the Apostle Philip were μεγάλας or great and splendid. I see a contrasting statement rather than an equivalent.

Comment: @Bʀɪᴀɴ If you would have submitted that as an answer, I probably would have chose it. NonTheologian beat you to it though. But I agree, that miracle was definitely strange and unheard of. Thank you.

Comment: @anonymouswho - Probably for the best, since NonTheologian's answer is better than what I would have put.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

τυχουσας is actually a participle, from the verb τυγχάνω, which can mean "obtain", "receive", "attain", "experience".  The phrase οὐχ ὁ τυχών occurs here as well as in Acts 28:2 -

> **Acts 28:2** (NKJV)
>
> > *And the natives showed us unusual* [οὐ τὴν τυχοῦσαν] *kindness; for they kindled a fire and made us all welcome, because of the rain that
> >     was falling and because of the cold.*

A more literal translation from the Greek might be:

> *And by the hands of Paul God kept on performing works of power -* [works] *not happening* [before]  ...

Most versions try to capture the sense of οὐχ ὁ τυχών in a single word, as you observe:

> **Acts 19:11** (KJV 1900)
>
> > *And God wrought **special** miracles by the hands of Paul:*
>
> **Acts 19:11** (NKJV)
>
> > *Now God worked **unusual** miracles by the hands of Paul,*
>
> **Acts 19:11**  (RSV)
>
> > *And God did **extraordinary** miracles by the hands of Paul,*
>
> **Acts 19:11**  (NASB95)
>
> > *God was performing **extraordinary** miracles by the hands of Paul,*
>
> **Acts 19:11**  (NIV)
>
> > *God did **extraordinary** miracles through Paul,*

Young's Literal Translation reduces οὐχ ὁ τυχών to "not common".

The only translation I am aware of that attempts to preserve the participial form is the *The Orthodox New Testament*, published by Holy Apostles Convent (2000):

> *And by the hands of Paul, God kept on performing works of power - not the ordinary ones which happen*

Comment: Great answer! So these were works of miraculous power that were not ordinarily done. That's all I was wanting to know. Thank you NonTheologian.